# how to know what happanes when I click on button

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, web-crawler

I want to get a content of one site by request using python.
But I see the information of the same city all the time.
The city selection button is

```
<input name="submit" value="Выбрать" class="btn btn_red" type="submit">
```

But I cannot find any logic which is related to that button inside the source.
The logic of the site is:
Cookies contain a PHPSESSID variable which provides information about the chosen city. Without this variable I can only see one default city.
When I change the city, PHPSESSID fixates it and provides information about the chosen city.

The problem is to get this variable. The Site uses JS, but I don't want to use phantomjs etc. I want to repeat the logic by myself.

Maybe it's possible to get the city data without that variable?

Comment: if your `button` be inside a `form` tag and form has `action`, then by click on `button`, the form will `POST`(or `GET`) to `action`.

Comment: You should to check, is any additional data loads by clicking this button. DevTools->Network will help.